# no clear info about git merge reversing one of changes (or: a merge which ignores all changes from one of merged hashes)

Tags: git, merge, history

I have a git repo in a strange state caused by a merge by another developer. I cannot contact him at the moment to ask how he created this merge, and I need to understand what has happened. I don't even know how to reproduce this merge mistake.

The main questions for me are

- once a problem is spotted: how to see which merge reversed a change?
- how to review all history to check if there are any other similar cases?
- how to avoid this in the future (what is the best guess of what was done during the merge)?

---

The git history looks as follows:

```
git log --graph --oneline --full-history -m --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset)'
*   4d1b542
|\
| * 72f242c
| * a73adb2
| * 8151f06
| * 6258abc
* | 745a5d5
* |   fe6f3c8
|\ \
| |/
| * d4ad1ee
| * 7a5d9a9
| * 79d1cf8
| * 00a3a06
| * e87b4b3
| * ebe39aa
| * 5eeec29
....
* | f2af11e
|/
*   3af4c69
```

Now, it seems that the merge fe6f3c8 was not done carefully enough, and the changes from 5eeec29, ebe39aa and so on are not in the final code and (1) it is not easy to spot and (2) once spotted not easy to investigate.

Changes from 5eeec29 can be viewed by "git show":

```
git show 5eeec29
...
diff --git a/src/node_management.c b/src/node_management.c
```

(and there are some specific substantial code changes in this diff).

Full git log of this file shows:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
    fe6f3c84e55613e7c042f66b865e96fc9f0f6782
git log --graph --oneline --full-history -m src/node_management.c

    *   fe6f3c8 Merge ...
    |\
    | * 5eeec29 
    | *   337b01b Merge ...
    | |\
    |/ /
    | * 4d69087 Merge ...
    |/
    *   3af4c69 Merge ...
    |\
    | *   032221e Merge ...
    | |\
    | |/
    |/|
    * | 394e416 Merge ...
    * | d2c4baa 
    |/
    *   0d60f7b Merge ...
```

(only d2c4baa and 5eeec29 are not-merge changes).

But the normal (simplified) log of this file shows only d2c4baa and older changes:

```
git log --graph --oneline -m src/node_management.c
* d2c4baa 
* cadc771 
* d6233c0
```

So git knows that 5eeec29 can be simplified out, it does not influence the final code. And the only next change reported in the --full-history is the merge fe6f3c8.

---

1. "git show fe6f3c8" does NOT mention this file at all. It is kind of OK: fe6f3c8 is a merge

   Merge: f2af11e d4ad1ee

and f2af11e..fe6f3c8 does not have any changes to the above file. The diff "is" in what was not picked up from the other branch d4ad1ee..fe6f3c8.

Is there an easy/standard way to see substantial changes from a merged branch which were not applied in a merge (effectively: reversed)?

2. How to review all the git history for all the code to spot this kind of mistakes? Ofc, the merge could have been correct, it is just about detecting items to review. I thought about a script that would:

   - go file-by-file
   - for each do "git log" and "git log --full-history" and look for lines that differ and that are not Merge commits

If there is a not-merge commit that does not pop-up in a normal (simplified) git log it means it was reverted. Any easier/better idea?

3. Could you help me in guessing what has happened during the merge fe6f3c8? What did the developer do? During the merge fe6f3c8 there were no conflicts in any file which was modified in 5eeec29. I really don't know what to do to reproduce this. I've created 2 branches based on f2af11e and d4ad1ee, and I tried to merge them both ways, resolve conflicts etc. and I cannot get to the same situation as in fe6f3c8.

Any idea what the developer had to do to loose completely in the merge all changes from 5eeec29, ebe39aa, e87b4b3 and so on? It looks like f2af11e and d4ad1ee got "merged" in such a way that all changes from d4ad1ee were completely ignored (not applied) even if they did not lead to any conflicts.

(As I wrote, I cannot contact this developer at the moment to ask how he created this merge, and I need to understand what has happened. It should not matter, but note: he does not use plain command-line git, he uses TortoiseGit ui.)